# Create pages on site pages (or pages) with a workflow

Tags: workflow, pages

I'd like to automate the creation of a page (in Site Pages or eventually in Pages) through a workflow.
While I can easily create documents (based on CT or template) so far I was unable to create the .aspx page.
I have found one similar question here, but without valid answer.
I have tried both 2010 and 2013 WF unsuccessfully.

Comment: Before you invest loads of time, be aware Microsoft is changing all this Page stuff in the Modern Experiences, so development you do now will only work in what they call "Classic" mode. And all they have said about that is that they will support Classic mode **well into 2017** .. https://blogs.office.com/2016/06/07/modern-document-libraries-in-sharepoint/ ... in my calendar that is next year.. so for I now I read it as: by the end of 2017 Microsoft may kill Classic mode (in SharePoint Online or future versions)

Comment: It is a nightmare, then... but i also have fund this: 
(...) And when you want to customize the home page, we are committed to enabling page configuration (choosing web parts, adding text) and extensibility (writing custom code) in our modern experiences going forward—inclusive of continuity for customers taking advantage of extensibility in classic experiences for the foreseeable future. We plan to add support for customizing the home page using modern development techniques. Existing customized home pages will remain in classic mode.

Answer (score 1):

Versus a workflow, is creating a link to the content type (Page or Web Part Page) an option?

1. Add the content type/s to a library.
2. Add the library to a web page as a web part and set its toolbar to display.
3. View the page’s source code and copy the code for the new button/template.
4. Enter the code into a CEWP for a link to the content type.

For step-by-step instructions view my post on creating links to document content type templates [here](https://jennyssharepointtips.wordpress.com/2014/07/30/launch-document-content-type-templates-from-any-web-page-with-a-link/).

Alternatively, I’m wondering if there is a way you could grab the New.aspx web page URL and add that as a link in a CEWP.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Jenny, but I have difficulties to apply your suggestion in a O365 environment. I tried the "shortcut" you suggest at the end, but so far no success: the link is not accepted by the system.

Comment: Is the link not being accepted because it is too long?  I’ve run into that problem before.   My solution was to shorten the site URL and page name.  For the shortcut, In SP2013 these are the steps I take to grab the new page link:
1. Go to a Pages or Site Pages library.
2. In settings, make visible only the content type you want to create/save.  
3.  In the library, on the ribbon, click New.  An ASPX entry form opens in the browser.  Copy the URL.
4. Add the URL to a text file.
5. On a web page in the site, add either a Script Editor wp or Content Editor wp and link to the text file.

Answer (score -1):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

http://www.connectorman.com/create-sites-with-spd-2013-workflow/

Its a long read, but very informative with pictures.

Comment: Flat Banana, can you try and include the points from the article that answer his question? I agree this is a valid, helpful link, but it will be more resilient if you can include the essential part(s).

Comment: While I do agree with both of you, the process of completing the OPs task is extensive in the number of steps.  Finding the necessary specific information to fit him from the referenced site would be difficult.  Please delete if you see fit.